# generated SQL Query changes based on different selection in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am converting an SQL query to LINQ. It has multiple inner, left and right joins. I'm checking the generated SQL from LINQ in every step. But the problem is based on the selection the generated sql query changes.

Below my Linq

```
var a = from freight in billingEntity.FreightCharges.AsNoTracking()
                        join service in billingEntity.ServiceTypes.AsNoTracking()
                        on freight.ServiceTypeId equals service.Id

                        join transport in billingEntity.TransportationTypes.AsNoTracking()
                        on freight.TransportationTypeId equals transport.Id

                        join division in billingEntity.DivisionDetails.AsNoTracking()
                        on freight.OriginId equals division.OriginID

                        join mail in billingEntity.Mailclasses.AsNoTracking()
                        on freight.MailClassId equals mail.MailClassId
                        into mailClassFreight

                        from mail in mailClassFreight.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join process in billingEntity.ProcessingCategories.AsNoTracking()
                        on freight.ProcessingcategoryId equals process.ProcessingCategoryId
                        into processFreight

                        from processCategory in processFreight.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select mail;
                string v = a.ToString();
```

This generated SQL as

```
SELECT 
    [Extent3].[MailClassId] AS [MailClassId], 
    [Extent3].[MailClassName] AS [MailClassName], 
    [Extent3].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate]
    FROM   [dbo].[FreightCharges] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DivisionDetails] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[OriginId] = [Extent2].[OriginID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Mailclass] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[MailClassId] = [Extent3].[MailClassId]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ServiceTypeId] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[TransportationTypeId] IS NOT NULL)
```

Where I can see the `dbo.ProcessingCategory` is missing in the join.

If I do `select processCategory` the SQL generates with missing `dbo.MailClass`.

The SQL query I am trying to convert to LINQ is below

```
select * from 
dbo.FreightCharges as fc
inner join dbo.ServiceType as st
on fc.ServiceTypeId = st.Id
inner join dbo.TransportationTypes as tt
on fc.TransportationTypeId = tt.Id
inner join dbo.DivisionDetails as dd
on fc.OriginId = dd.OriginId
left join dbo.Mailclass as mc
on fc.MailClassId = mc.MailClassId
left join dbo.ProcessingCategory as pc
on fc.ProcessingcategoryId = pc.ProcessingCategoryId
right join dbo.ContentTitle as ct
on fc.ContentTitleId = ct.ContentTitleId
inner join dbo.AccountDetails as ac
on ct.AccountId = ac.AccountId
where 
fc.EffectiveThruDate >= '9999-12-31'
or 
fc.EffectiveThruDate is null
```

Comment: so you want to select all coulmns of every table joined or just `FrieghtCharges` table ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad well I need some selected columns. But I figured that if I select columns from all the tables the joins become correct and `MailClass` and `ProcessingCategory` coming with proper joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your query joins to left joins like this.

```
select * from 
dbo.ContentTitle ct
inner join dbo.AccountDetails as ac
    on ct.AccountId = ac.AccountId
left join dbo.FreightCharges as fc
    on fc.ContentTitleId = ct.ContentTitleId and fc.EffectiveThruDate >= '9999-12-31'
left join dbo.ServiceType as st
    on fc.ServiceTypeId = st.Id
left join dbo.TransportationTypes as tt
    on fc.TransportationTypeId = tt.Id
left join dbo.DivisionDetails as dd
    on fc.OriginId = dd.OriginId
left join dbo.Mailclass as mc
    on fc.MailClassId = mc.MailClassId
left join dbo.ProcessingCategory as pc
    on fc.ProcessingcategoryId = pc.ProcessingCategoryId
```

Linq equivalent

```
from ct in ContentTitles
join ac in AccountDetails on ct.AccountId equals ac.AccountId 
join fc in FreightCharges on ct.ContentTitleId equals fc.ContentTitleId into lfc
from flfc in lfc.Where(f => f.EffectiveThruDate >= new DateTime(9999,12,31)).DefaultIfEmpty()   
join st in ServiceTypes on flfc.ServiceTypeId equals st.Id into lst
from flst in lst.DefaultIfEmpty()   
join tt in TransportationTypes on flfc.TransportationTypeId equals tt.Id into ltt
from fltt in ltt.DefaultIfEmpty()   
join dd in DivisionDetails on flfc.OriginId equals dd.OriginId into ldd
from fldd in ldd.DefaultIfEmpty()   
join mc in Mailclasses on flfc.MailClassId equals mc.MailClassId into lmc
from flmc in lst.DefaultIfEmpty()   
join pc in ProcessingCategories on flfc.ProcessingcategoryId equals pc.ProcessingCategoryId into lpc
from flpc in lst.DefaultIfEmpty()   
select new {ct, ac, lfc, lst ,ltt, ldd, lmc, lpc}
```